# When making a Wild Empathy check, do any of the bonuses from Diplomacy apply?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, druid, ranger, social-combat

When making a Wild Empathy check, do any of the bonuses from Diplomacy apply? Ranks, skill focus, traits, etc.

The ability says:

> This ability functions just like a Diplomacy check to improve the attitude of a person.

But it also says:

> The ranger rolls 1d20 and adds his ranger level and his Charisma bonus to determine the wild empathy check result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, they don't apply.

Wild empathy works just like Diplomacy in terms of when you roll, how long it takes to do something that requires a check, and what the effects of your check are. But it uses a different roll, namely class levels plus Charisma, from Diplomacy. Diplomacy skill ranks, bonuses to Diplomacy skill checks or to Charisma-based skill checks, and the like do not apply to wild empathy checks. To gain bonuses to wild empathy, the bonus must either specify wild empathy itself, or else apply to all Charisma-based checks (rather than ability checks or skill checks specifically).